# Why isn't readSync necessary in this sample code?

Tags: node.js

In this tutorial http://www.dotnetcurry.com/nodejs/1270/read-html-file-and-send-html-response-nodejs

```
    //1.
    var http = require('http');
    var fs = require('fs');
    //2.
    var server = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
        //3.
        if (req.url === "/create") {
            fs.readFile("AppPages/MyPage.html", function (error, pgResp) {
                if (error) {
                    resp.writeHead(404);
                    resp.write('Contents you are looking are Not Found');
                } else {
                    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    resp.write(pgResp);
                }

                resp.end();
            });
        } else {
            //4.
            resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
            resp.write('<h1>Product Manaager</h1><br /><br />To create product please enter: ' + req.url);
            resp.end();
        }
    });
    //5.
    server.listen(5050);
```

I don't understand since readFile is asynchronous why it would work reliably if the page takes a long time to load ? So is readSync necessary here or something allows waiting for the page to be fully read even if the file is very big ?

Comment: That's the async basics. The function in the callback of readFile will be run only when the file has been fully read. So no matter the size or time it takes, the function gets executed after it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works properly because the execution of the function that is defined in the parameters of readFile (this function is called callback function btw) happens only when the file has been read.

Comment: do you have a link which explicitely says it is async or explain the internals of this part ? thanks.

Comment: readFile is not async, you can check the nodejs documentation about this (https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback). I suggest you also to read about the callbacks: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function